# Android WiFi connection programmatically

Tags: android, connection, wifi

Do you have any idea how to establish a wifi connection with sending password in my android application?

Answer (score 31):

Pass the SSID and it's password to the following method.

```
public void connectToAP(String ssid, String passkey) {
    Log.i(TAG, "* connectToAP");

    WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();

    String networkSSID = ssid;
    String networkPass = passkey;

    Log.d(TAG, "# password " + networkPass);

    for (ScanResult result : scanResultList) {
        if (result.SSID.equals(networkSSID)) {

            String securityMode = getScanResultSecurity(result);

            if (securityMode.equalsIgnoreCase("OPEN")) {

                wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
                wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                int res = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
                Log.d(TAG, "# add Network returned " + res);

                boolean b = wifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);
                Log.d(TAG, "# enableNetwork returned " + b);

                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

            } else if (securityMode.equalsIgnoreCase("WEP")) {

                wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
                wifiConfiguration.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
                wifiConfiguration.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
                wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
                int res = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
                Log.d(TAG, "### 1 ### add Network returned " + res);

                boolean b = wifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);
                Log.d(TAG, "# enableNetwork returned " + b);

                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            }

            wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
            wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
            wifiConfiguration.hiddenSSID = true;
            wifiConfiguration.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
            wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
            wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
            wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
            wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
            wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
            wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
            wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);

            int res = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
            Log.d(TAG, "### 2 ### add Network returned " + res);

            wifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);

            boolean changeHappen = wifiManager.saveConfiguration();

            if(res != -1 && changeHappen){
                Log.d(TAG, "### Change happen");

                AppStaticVar.connectedSsidName = networkSSID;

            }else{
                Log.d(TAG, "*** Change NOT happen");
            }

            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}

public String getScanResultSecurity(ScanResult scanResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "* getScanResultSecurity");

    final String cap = scanResult.capabilities;
    final String[] securityModes = { "WEP", "PSK", "EAP" };

    for (int i = securityModes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (cap.contains(securityModes[i])) {
            return securityModes[i];
        }
    }

    return "OPEN";
}
```

Don't forget to add necessary permission in the Manifest file.

Comment: This code does not compile, where are defined the variables scanResultList and wifiManager?

Comment: You will need to get the WifiManager wifiManager (Context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)) and do a call on it (wifiMananger.getScanResults()) to get the scanResultList variable. The code above assumes you already have a list of available networks.

Answer (score 7):

100% Works.

By this way you can connect to your specific Wifi
 This code for MainActivity.java

////////////// >>> Wifi Connection (WP2) <<<  ////////////////

```
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();

        wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", "Wifi name");
        wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", "Wifi password");

        WifiManager wifiManager=(WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
        wifiManager.reconnect();
```

And Also don't forget to include this code to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 3):

The code posted from [AnujAroshA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14134391/5389530) here is really helpful. But there is an else case missing:

```
  ..
  } else if (securityMode.equalsIgnoreCase("PSK")) {
    // PSK code
  ..
```

Otherwise the PSK code is executed for WEP and OPEN networks, too.

And code style is not optimal in my opinion. It is unnecessary to create the two Strings networkSSID and networkPass. You can simply use ssid or passkey.

Suggestion: Split creating the wifi configuration and connect method.

(1) Method for creating the WifiConfiguration:

```
private WifiConfiguration createAPConfiguration(String networkSSID, String networkPasskey, String securityMode) {
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();

        wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";

        if (securityMode.equalsIgnoreCase("OPEN")) {

            wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

        } else if (securityMode.equalsIgnoreCase("WEP")) {

            wifiConfiguration.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + networkPasskey + "\"";
            wifiConfiguration.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
            wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
            wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);

        } else if (securityMode.equalsIgnoreCase("PSK")) {

            wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPasskey + "\"";
            wifiConfiguration.hiddenSSID = true;
            wifiConfiguration.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
            wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
            wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
            wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
            wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
            wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
            wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
            wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);

        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "# Unsupported security mode: "+securityMode);

            return null;
        }

        return wifiConfiguration;

    }
```

(2) Method for the AP connect:

```
    public int connectToAP(String networkSSID, String networkPasskey) {
    for (ScanResult result : scanResultList) {

        if (result.SSID.equals(networkSSID)) {

            String securityMode = getScanResultSecurity(result);

            WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = createAPConfiguration(networkSSID, networkPasskey, securityMode);

            int res = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
            Log.d(TAG, "# addNetwork returned " + res);

            boolean b = wifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);
            Log.d(TAG, "# enableNetwork returned " + b);

            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

            boolean changeHappen = wifiManager.saveConfiguration();

            if (res != -1 && changeHappen) {
                Log.d(TAG, "# Change happen");
                connectedSsidName = networkSSID;
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "# Change NOT happen");
            }

            return res;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

(3) The scan method 100% as posted [AnujAroshA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14134391/5389530).

```
public String getScanResultSecurity(ScanResult scanResult) {

    final String cap = scanResult.capabilities;
    final String[] securityModes = { "WEP", "PSK", "EAP" };

    for (int i = securityModes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (cap.contains(securityModes[i])) {
            return securityModes[i];
        }
    }

    return "OPEN";
}
```

Comment: Please Give A Method of  `scanResultList`

Answer (score 0):

Give your ssid and password

```
    fun connectToWifi(ssid: String, password: String) {
    val connManager = context!!.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
    val wifiConfiguration = WifiConfiguration()
    wifiConfiguration.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid)
    wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", password)
    wifiManager = context!!.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
    val netId: Int = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration)
    wifiManager.disconnect()
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true)
    wifiManager.reconnect()
    val config = WifiConfiguration()
    config.SSID == "\"\"" + ssid + "\"\""
    config.preSharedKey == "\"\"" + password + "\"\""
    wifiManager.addNetwork(config)
}
```