# Custom Android Wifi Manager - Stored passwords

Tags: android, networking, wifi, android-wifi

I want to incorporate a wifi manager into my app to keep the flow of the app simple. I have a list of available networks from [WifiManager.getScanResults](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults()). I have allowed a user to connect to a network using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517314/android-wifi-connection-programmatically). Where I pull the SSID from the ScanResult and the password from an input TextView.

I would like to make use of the users stored wifi passwords, as can be seen in the default Android wifi manager. Is it possible to e.g. automatically connect to a network, if a stored password is available? Maybe by firing a "connect to wifi network" intent, similar to a "start Android wifi manager" intent?

I understand Android would not give out the stored passwords directly for security reasons.

I would prefer to avoid sending the user to the default Android wifi manager, but maybe that is the best solution.

I can't see anything that does what I need in the [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can store store the password against SSID in local database.
and check if SSID is available and its password is already is stored in the database then connect to it . 
Android would not give out the stored passwords directly for security reasons.