# WifiConfiguration setting wifi programmatically working in ide but not as an app

Tags: java, android

so I am working on an app for my company and we have devices that run android api 27 and 28 so I need to add support for setting the wifi programmatically using the depricated WifiConfiguration flow.

I have it setup and when running from the IDE (debug and normal run) then the auto connection runs completely fine, but when being run as an app, installed by an apk it does not connect to the wifi programmatically.

Goal:
Connect from current wifi network to a different wifi network programmatically.

Code:

```
// wifiConfiguration is a configuration I created and added in the wifiManager
for (WifiConfiguration configuredNetwork : wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()) {
    if (configuredNetwork.SSID.equals(wifiConfiguration.SSID)) {
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(configuredNetwork.networkId, true); // have tried false as well.
        wifiManager.reconnect();
        return true;
   }
}
```

I have also tried disabling all networks and then enabling only the one I need same result.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What the result status via `NetworkInfo.getDetailedState()`? Try reconnecting in a loop. Give some time lets say 5 seconds, check the status, if failed, reconnecting. Or better check the status in parallel when connecting using a thread or handler.

Comment: Plus, make sure to set wifi configurations correctly (`WifiConfiguration`). See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517314/android-wifi-connection-programmatically).